# Use one csv file to delete duplicates in another one

Tags: csv

Basically the title says it all. I have a csv list that includes one e-mail address per line (and some other stuff). I want to seek those email addresses in a different csv file (also with 1 mail address and other stuff per line) and then delete those duplicates in the second list.

Is there any tool I could use for that or would I have to write my own little script? - I would use PHP as this is the only language I really 'speak', although my guess is that it's quite inconvinient for this purpose. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: What OS are yoou on?

Comment: Do you have access to Microsoft Office or Open Office. This is a cinch on either. You wouldn't need to worry about any coding.

Comment: I'm on Mac OS X Snow Leopard, Open Office would be a solution. Where could I find such a tool in OO @Jay ?